# CUDA OpenMP Libraries are not found - Mavericks OsX 10.9

Tags: macos, cuda, openmp, osx-mavericks, sample

I have Mavericks OsX 10.9.1  on a Macbook Pro 15" late 2008 with Nvidia Geforce 9400M and 9600M GT.
Latest Xcode 5.0.2 Installed.

I've installed the last Cuda software 5.5.28 and I got this error trying to compile some samples.

make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
find: /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64: No such file or directory

### WARNING - CUDA OpenMP Libraries are not found

CUDA Samples "cudaOpenMP" cannot be built without libgomp libraries.
This will be a dry-run of the Makefile.
For more information on how to set up your environment to build and run this 
sample, please refer the CUDA Samples documentation and release notes

There are no relevant topics on Nvidia Forum website,  can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clang compiler that ships in XCode 5 does not support OpenMP. You will not be be able to build that example.

Comment: I can't -   no Cuda capable device is detected -   I don't know why.
With the previos OS, everything worked perfectly

Comment: You can't what? You asked about building the OpenMP example, and I explained why you cannot do that with Xcode 5. What does your comment have to do with either your question or my answer?

Comment: sorry I've answered to the wrong topic, I had 2 problems related